# How to maximize window in Jenkins using Python, Selenium Webdriver and Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, maximize

How to maximize a window in Jenkins?
I tried to maximize window using:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)


driver.maximize_window()

driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)

driver.fullscreen_window()
```

All works when I run the test in PyCharm, but in Jenkins, the window does not change size.

Comment: How are you running Jenkins?

Comment: What do you mean? localhost:8080

Comment: Do you have it installed as a windows service?

Comment: Maybe not. How to check?

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes, windows 10

Comment: In that case, check in Administrative Tools -> Services.

Comment: I have Jenkins in services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with Jenkins running as a windows service.

In Windows command prompt, go to folder where jenkins-cli.jar file is located.

And stop the service.

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 safe-shutdown --username "YourUsername" 
--password "YourPassword"
```

Have Jenkins run from the command prompt using a script.